# How to select specific columns from lots of dataframes in r

Tags: r

I am handling 303 data frames and each data frame has different name as well as contains different columns. What I want is that select specific columns of which name contain "_CD" and "_NM" from those lots of data frames. Is there any good way to deal with it?

Note, those data frames were not listed.

Here is an example (I cannot bring up the real data but show you the fake with similar format)

table 1 name: AD_ITEM_CNT;

- columns : CKND_CLSF_CD, SUBJ_CD, ITEM_CNT, UPDT_DT

table 2 name : BLAD_PE_XEXM

- columns : PT_SBST_NO, CEXM_NM, CEXM_CD, CEXM_RST, CEX_RSLT_CMNT, LDNG_DT

table 3 name : BLAD_MR_HLTH

- columns : PT_SBST_NO, RGST_DT, EDU_DGRE_CD, DRNK_YN, JOB_KIND_CD ...

The goal of this process is to create a table like the below

```
Table          |       column |  CD 
-----------------------------------
AD_ITEM_CNT    | CKND_CLSF_CD |  01
AD_ITEM_CNT    | CKND_CLSF_CD |  02
AD_ITEM_CNT    | CKND_CLSF_CD |  03
AD_ITEM_CNT    | CKND_CLSF_CD |  04
BLAD_PE_XEXM   | CEXM_CD      |  AVS
BLAD_PE_XEXM   | CEXM_CD      |  ABE
BLAD_PE_XEXM   | CEXM_CD      |  CVS
BLAD_PE_XEXM   | CEXM_CD      |  UVS
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Can you create a minimal reproducible example so it is easier for people to test their code? Maybe also show what you have tried?

Comment: I'm hoping that you have all 303 frames contained within a single `list` ... if not, I strongly suggest ... no, *urge* you to consider it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/. This might be as simple as `lapply(list_of_frames, function(x) x[, grepl("cy", names(x)), drop=FALSE])`.

Comment: @r2evans or make all the dataframes in the global workspace into a list with `my_list <- as.list(.GlobalEnv); my_list <- my_list[sapply(my_list, class) == "data.frame"]`

Comment: AllanCameron, in my view, that's an acceptable method to get to the point of using a list-of-frames ... but if it is followed by anything that `assign`s them back to the global, them I'm definitely "out".

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. I added example and the specified the goal of this process. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Sangwon, I suggest you look at two things: (1) Good links on how to ask a question *well* so that it can quickly be tested and answered by others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. (2) Less critically, how to format a question well so that it reads better (code text versus paragraph text, etc): https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting.

Comment: Some specifics: your data is not in a format easily digestible, if done well, we can just copy and paste it into the R terminal and have nothing to worry about. The gold-standard for this is either programmatically building data (e.g., `data.frame(...)`) or the output from `dput(head(x))`, but some tables might be clear-enough if you paste the `data.frame` representation on the console (though there are many many times this does not work well enough).

Comment: BTW: inability to show real data is common, you just need to spend a moment and reduce the problem as much as you can and inject *fake* but *representative-enough* data. That is, if you need a string, integer, or floating-point, you may not need real or accurate numbers.

Comment: You say you want to *"select specific columns"* but it appears that you are counting them or something similar. Can you clarify what you have, what you need, how you think you need to get there, and any code you've tried so far?

Comment: Okay. so, the dataset that I am dealing with is based on clinical information. Each data frame contains different set of medical information. For instance, AD_ITEM_CNT table contains medical records of treatment prescription for each patients who have visited a hospital.

Comment: Columns ending with "_CD" or "_NM" indicates factor formatted variables.

Comment: Ddi you try r2evans' suggestion? Can you put all the data in a list so that it is easy to manage? You can then select specific column easily from it.

Answer (score 0):

As @r2evans said, I more than encourage you to start with loading all your `data.frame`s into one `list`. However, if you don't have any other option, you can do this:

First, lets create 5 `data.frame`s:

```
for (i in 1:5) { 

  set.seed(123)
  assign(paste0("y",i), data.frame(A_CD = rnorm(1), 
                                   A_NM = rnorm(1), 
                                   A_GK = rnorm(1)))

}
```

Next, we can create a list of all of our variables (using `ls()`) and filter (`Filter`) for only the `data.frames`:

```
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))
```

Lastly, we can filter the `data.frame`s inside the list for the needed columns (have CD and NM in them):

```
dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(x) x[, grepl("CD|NM", names(x)), drop=FALSE])
```

Output:

```
dfs

$y1
        A_CD       A_NM
1 -0.5604756 -0.2301775

$y2
        A_CD       A_NM
1 -0.5604756 -0.2301775

$y3
        A_CD       A_NM
1 -0.5604756 -0.2301775

$y4
        A_CD       A_NM
1 -0.5604756 -0.2301775

$y5
        A_CD       A_NM
1 -0.5604756 -0.2301775
```